# How in Godot Engine 2D to realize the visibility zone of an object?

Tags: godot

How in Godot Engine 2D to realize the visibility zone of an object? Help
Here is the code, but it does not work:

```
if position.x-C.cox<100:
    if position.x>C.cox:
        velocity.x-=30
    if position.x<C.cox:
        velocity.x+=30
if position.y-C.coy<100:
    if position.y>C.coy:
        velocity.y-=30
    if position.y<C.coy:
        velocity.y+=30
```

C.cox - position of the pursued goal in x, C.coy - position of the pursued goal in y.

Comment: I recommend using an [Area2D](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/physics/using_area_2d.html) for visibility zone.

For implementing a pursuit agent it will be simpler and scalable to use [Navigation2D](https://youtu.be/0fPOt0Jw52s).

Comment: If you're only looking for a point or an object intersection instead of a full area, you could always use Raycast2D. However, for an area, I agree with hola - use Area2D